# How to convert downloaded images to int image IDs (for use with an ArrayAdapter)?

Tags: android, image, imageview

I have images available via a movie database, that provides the path to the image online (which I have stored in a Movie object). I want to download these images and display them with a custom ArrayAdapter, but I don't know how to download images to be referenced by an image ID. Here is the code;

Class that represents a movie, containing a title, posterpath for downloading via the internet,  the integer for the posterImg downloaded locally (unsure how to find this):

```
public class Movie {
    protected String id;
    protected String posterPath;
    protected String title;
    //TODO pass in image reference
    protected int posterImg;
    private final String LOG_TAG = Movie.class.getSimpleName();

    public Movie(String id, String posterPath, String title){
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return posterPath;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getPoster() { return posterImg; }
}
```

Custom ArrayAdapter with only a few methods:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MovieAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public MovieAdapter(Activity context, List<Movie> movies){
        super(context, 0, movies);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        Movie movie = getItem(position);

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_movie, parent, false);
        }

        ImageView iconView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon);
        iconView.setImageResource(movie.getPoster());

        TextView titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
        titleView.setText(movie.getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

How should I import these images and display them, using this method or another? I've looked around at things like the LazyList library, but I couldn't figure out how to import it into my project. I'd also like to know how to do this using this method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Glide to handle downloading,  caching and displaying image all with just one line of code. You just donot need to handle ids.

ImageView targetImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

String internetUrl = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5w9Z.jpg";

Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(internetUrl)
    .into(targetImageView);

Read more about it here

https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-getting-started